# retrieving all tuples except one with a sub-query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to retrieve all the users with the same country name, but except the user, I am comparing with other. this query gives me an error saying that the sub query returns more than one row. anyone can help me in this regard, please.

```
SELECT * FROM users u, address a WHERE a.email=u.email AND a.country LIKE (SELECT country FROM address WHERE NOT (email = 'ta@gmail.com'));
```

Comment: try to use IN instead of LIKE

Comment: try to replace `like` with `in`

Comment: but now it is not filtering the data according to the country of 'ta@gmail.com'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select *
from users u, address a
where a.email=u.email
and a.country = (select country from address where email = 'ta@gmail.com')
and u.email <> 'ta@gmail.com'
```

OR

```
select *
from users u, address a,
(select country from address where email = 'ta@gmail.com') c
where a.email=u.email
and a.country = c.country
and u.email <> 'ta@gmail.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your question before. Try this,

```
SELECT * FROM users s
JOIN address a on a.email = u.email 
WHERE a.country in(SELECT country from address where email = 'ta@gmail.com')
AND a.email != 'ta@gmail.com'
```

Comment: but now it is not filtering the data according to the country of 'ta@gmail.com'

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
SELECT * FROM users u, address a 
  WHERE a.email=u.email 
  AND u.email != 'ta@gmail.com'
  AND a.country IN (SELECT country FROM address WHERE email ='ta@gmail.com');
```

Comment: but now it is not filtering the data according to the country of 'ta@gmail.com'

Comment: as I understood from you, the result should contain all the users form any country except the country of the user with the email 'ta@gmail.com'. Is that what you want?

Comment: no, i want all the users which contain the same country as the 'ta@gmail.com' but i don't want 'ta@gmail.com' to appear in the result.

Comment: I've edited the answer. Please try it and see if it works!

Comment: the answer @dave has provided worked for me. thanks to all of you